# Update Google Chrome extensions from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, updates

How can I update Google Chrome extensions from the command line?

I'm running macOS 12.7.4.

Comment: Chrome developers aim to block such installations as a security risk. There are many published methods that claim to do just that, but sooner of later they stop working. Even if you find a working solution today, you can't depend upon its working tomorrow.

Comment: "instructions for all applicable OSes" - This makes your question extremely broad which is an indication you must narrow the scope of the question to be specific.

Comment: @Ramhound it isn't overly broad. Chrome seems to run on 3 platforms that have command lines: macOS, Windows, and Linux. If someone just wants to help me, they can supply info for macOS. If they want to be helpful for others, they can supply instructions for 2 more platforms. That isn't hard.

Comment: @XDR while it's good trying to help others, your goal is to get answers for YOUR problem, not others. That is one reason this site is about single specific questions that can be answered with single specific answers. You could post 3 questions, one for each OS, and that would be fine, and even encouraged here, especially if the commands differ between OSes.

Comment: Another thing you can do to improve your question is to share with us what research you have done and what you have tried yourself to resolve this.

Comment: @XDR - I strongly disagree that asking for instructions for 3 or more operating systems isn't broad. My thought on this matter cannot be swayed and I believe the help center backs me up.